# How do you make a new collider?

Tags: modeling, animation, collision, soft-body

I'm currently working on an obstacle course for some soft-body balls to go through, and I'm right now stuck on creating a funnel. I'm trying to make the balls go through the funnel, but there's clipping through the sides of it. I'm trying to make a new collider so the balls can go through the funnel without any clipping, but I'm stuck on that. I was told that I had to duplicate the collider and move vertices around, but I don't know how to do that.

I've also noticed that when I recalculated normals on the inside of the funnel, one of the balls lingers in it for a while, bouncing inside it for a while before it falls out like the rest of them.

Here's my file...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing your blend file which made me curious and easy to help you.

If you check these two options here:

[image]

Collision edge and face -> it works.

Before:

[image]

after:

[image]

> Note: Checking these options will need much more time for calculating
> your simulation.

So maybe a different camera angle might be the quicker solution ;)

Comment: Do the frames-per-second get slow when you have those boxes checked?

Comment: It depends what you mean with fps. Once you baked it, it’s fast. But this „one time baking“ is pretty slow. And of course it „normally“ is not just one time because you try to tweak and change it until you like it. But this tweaking you could do without these options checked because I assume that wouldn’t change so much of the end result.

Comment: The same issue of the blob balls clipping through an object has happened with the slide I created for them.