# How do you prevent soft-body balls from clipping through objects?

Tags: modeling, animation, soft-body

I've been working on a soft-body project where three soft-body ball "blobs" go through an obstacle course, and I want them to land on objects, but they clip through them. How do I solve that? I want to do that with every object in the simulation, but it's hard to do that because it takes a while for that to work. What I want is for the balls to land on different objects without any clipping, and that is something that I want to get better at.

Here is my file...
[image]

Comment: why are u asking the same question over and over again? i answered you here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248869/how-do-you-make-a-new-collider -> my solution prevents clipping. Why didn't you try that!?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

just give the slider some depth and and other collision objects some depth, it is not the solution but this will hide the clipping. exturde the surfaces of collision objects. the collision object is a single plane so i think there will always be clipping. when i work with planes the soft body always pass through.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).